# SQL Percentage - Conditional Sum

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to calculate percentage churn and retain values according to app language. I am using Snowflake.

My current is as follows:

```
SELECT i.language, lb.churn_status, SUM(lb.total_users) AS user_count
FROM level_based_churn_retain_comparison AS lb
    INNER JOIN sessions AS s
    ON s.level_index=lb.level_index
        INNER JOIN installs AS i
        ON s.user_id=i.user_id

GROUP BY i.language, lb.churn_status
ORDER BY i.language, user_count
```

And the output is

```
language churn_status user_count
```

Comment: please tag which RDMS you use?

Answer (score 0):

So with this very imaginative data (that I have in a CTE to make it easy for me)

```
with level_based_churn_retain_comparison(level_index, total_users, churn_status) as (
    select * from values
    (10, 100, 'a'),
    (20, 400, 'a'),
    (30, 300, 'a')
), installs(user_id, language) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 'en'),
    (2, 'en'),
    (3, 'fr')
), sessions(user_id, level_index) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 10),
    (2, 20),
    (3, 30)
)
```

your SQL + [RATIO_TO_REPORT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/ratio_to_report.html)

```
SELECT 
    i.language, 
    lb.churn_status, 
    SUM(lb.total_users) AS user_count,
    100.0 * ratio_to_report(user_count) over() as percent_churn
FROM level_based_churn_retain_comparison AS lb
INNER JOIN sessions AS s
    ON s.level_index = lb.level_index
INNER JOIN installs AS i
    ON s.user_id = i.user_id
GROUP BY i.language, lb.churn_status
ORDER BY i.language, user_count
```

we get:

| LANGUAGE | CHURN_STATUS | USER_COUNT | PERCENT_CHURN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| en | a | 500 | 62.5 |
| fr | a | 300 | 37.5 |

Now if you want the percentage to be per churn_status, we can put that into the PARTITION BY clause, like so:

```
with level_based_churn_retain_comparison(level_index, total_users, churn_status) as (
    select * from values
    (10, 100, 'a'),
    (20, 400, 'b'),
    (30, 300, 'a')
), installs(user_id, language) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 'en'),
    (2, 'en'),
    (3, 'fr')
), sessions(user_id, level_index) as (
    select * from values
    (1, 10),
    (2, 20),
    (3, 30)
)
SELECT 
    i.language, 
    lb.churn_status, 
    SUM(lb.total_users) AS user_count,
    100.0 * ratio_to_report(user_count) over(partition by lb.churn_status) as percent_churn
FROM level_based_churn_retain_comparison AS lb
INNER JOIN sessions AS s
    ON s.level_index = lb.level_index
INNER JOIN installs AS i
    ON s.user_id = i.user_id
GROUP BY i.language, lb.churn_status
ORDER BY i.language, user_count
```

giving:

| LANGUAGE | CHURN_STATUS | USER_COUNT | PERCENT_CHURN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| en | a | 100 | 25 |
| en | b | 400 | 100 |
| fr | a | 300 | 75 |